# Set textcolor only one tab on tablayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I want to set `textColor`only one tab on tablayout. One tab must have another color by default. 
Here is my Tablayout in XML

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

It make all tabs color white. 
I have tried this:

```
tabs_main.getTabAt(3)?.icon?.alpha = 225
```

but It doesn't work
How can I change one tab color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **alpha** you are changing the opacity of the inside text, not the color.

If this is what you want to achieve, then check if `tabs_main.getTabAt(3)` doesn't return **null**.

Otherwise, I suggest you to use a custom `TextView` inside the tab element.

Example:

Create a layout : **custom_text_view.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/customTabTextView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:textColor="@color/your_color"
      android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Add the layout as custom view for each tab item, and choose the desired `textColor` for each of them.

```
    (0..tabLayout.tabCount).forEach { position ->
        val customTextView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_text_view, null)
        // Set the text color
        customTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.<name_of_color>))
        tabLayout.getTabAt(position)?.customView = customTextView
    }
```